# I have applied CSS but elements are not coming to the center

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a small quiz app but I have applied css but the css is not working. I don't know why. Instead of showing elements in the middle of page it is showing elements in left bottom. Please tell me what should be the changes in css or in HTML. Or if the css is right please let me know how to middle all the elements in the page.

```css
:root {
    background-color: #ecf5ff;
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #333;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4{
   margin-bottom: 1rem; 
}
h1{
    font-size: 5.4rem;
    color: #56a5eb;
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
}
h1 > span{
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    font-weight: 500;
}
h2{
    font-size: 4.2rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
h3{
    font-size: 2.8rem;
    font-weight: 500;
}

/* UTILITIES */

.container{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 80 rem;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

.container > *{
    width: 100%;
}

.flex-column{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

}

.flex-center{
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.justify-center{
    justify-content: center;
}

.text-center{
    text-align: center;
}

.hidden{
    display: none;
}
/* BUTTONS */

.btn{
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    width: 20rem;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0.1rem solid #56a5eb;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #56a5eb;
    background-color: white;
}

.btn:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow:100 100 0.4rem 0 rgba(86, 185, 235, 0.5);
    transform: translate(-0.1rem);
    transition: transform 150ms;

}

.btn[disabled]:hover{
    cursor: not-allowed;
    box-shadow: none;
    transform: none;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <title>Quick Quiz</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container"></div>
    <div id="home" class="flex-center flex-column"></div>
        <h1>Quick Quiz!</h1>
        <a class="btn" href="/game.html">Play</a>
        <a class="btn" href="/highscores.html">High Scored</a>
</body>
</html>
```

[This is the output kindly click here to see the output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2ogi.png)

Comment: You'll need to share your CSS so that we can help.

Comment: Added the css and html in post.

Answer (score 2):

You have an issue with the `HTML`

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="home" class="flex-center flex-column">
    <h1>Quick Quiz!</h1>
    <a class="btn" href="/game.html">Play</a>
    <a class="btn" href="/highscores.html">High Scored</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

All you have to do is put your elements inside `<div id="home" class="flex-center flex-column"></div>` this div.